# Good feature extraction for handwritten characters using OpenCV python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, feature-extraction, handwriting-recognition

I'm currently using the cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack() method. However, the corners it returns are somewhat vague and doesn't really do what i wanted wherein it would put some dots on the outline of the character. Here is an attached image of how it worked on my custom dataset:
[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b10mW.png)

```
corners = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(crop, 8, 0.02, 10)
```

If cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack() is not a good way of extracting features from handwritten characters, what are some of the better ways to do it? Thank you

Comment: `cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack` is to find good corners, not suitable for characters. Hog feature is a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

Use Neural Networks you can preload trained models also in open cv. Here is short intro into the topic. Its a 1 to 1 tutorial :) Hope you like it. https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/09/22/getting-started-deep-learning-python/